# java - Return a value from Visitor

Tags: java, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

Suppose we have following classes which we can't change:

```
interface Base {
    void accept(Visitor visitor);
}

class Foo implements Base {
    short getShortValue() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

class Bar implements Base {
    int getIntValue() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

interface Visitor {
    void visit(Foo foo);

    void visit(Bar bar);
}
```

And we need to implement method:

```
 int getValue(Base base)
```

There are many possibilities to do it with visitor using some storage object:

```
int useArray(Base base) {
    int[] result = new int[1];

    base.accept(new Visitor() {
        @Override
        public void visit(Foo foo) {
            result[0] = foo.getShortValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(Bar bar) {
            result[0] = bar.getIntValue();
        }
    });

    return result[0];
}

int useAtomic(Base base) {
    AtomicInteger result = new AtomicInteger();

    base.accept(new Visitor() {
        @Override
        public void visit(Foo foo) {
            result.set(foo.getShortValue());
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(Bar bar) {
            result.set(bar.getIntValue());
        }
    });

    return result.intValue();
}

int useMutable(Base base) {
    MutableInteger result = new MutableInteger(0);

    base.accept(new Visitor() {
        @Override
        public void visit(Foo foo) {
            result.setValue(foo.getShortValue());
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(Bar bar) {
            result.setValue(bar.getIntValue());
        }
    });

    return result.getValue();
}
```

Or something perverted:

```
int useException(Base base) {
    class GotResult extends RuntimeException {
        private final int value;

        public GotResult(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    try {
        base.accept(new Visitor() {
            @Override
            public void visit(Foo foo) {
                throw new GotResult(foo.getShortValue());
            }

            @Override
            public void visit(Bar bar) {
                throw new GotResult(bar.getIntValue());
            }
        });
    } catch (GotResult result) {
        return result.value;
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

Or don't use visitor at all:

```
int useCast(Base base) {
    if (base instanceof Foo) {
        return ((Foo) base).getShortValue();
    }
    if (base instanceof Bar) {
        return ((Bar) base).getIntValue();
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

Are these our only options now? We have Java 8 (will have 9 soon enough) and still writing these ugly pieces of error-prone code. :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree that not being able to return a value from the visitor is terrible from a safe usage point of view.

To avoid the burden of the gymnastic you demonstrated above, your best option is to create a wrapper type that expose a sane API (based on the [corrected visitor pattern](http://logji.blogspot.ch/2012/02/correcting-visitor-pattern.html)) so that the dirty work is done only once: when converting a `Base` value to that wrapper type.

Here is how you could do it:

```java
interface BaseW {

    interface Cases<X> {
        X foo(Foo foo);
        X bar(Bar bar);
    }

    <X> X match(Cases<X> cases);
    //or alternatively, use a church encoding:
    //<X> X match(Function<Foo, X> foo, Function<Bar, X> bar);

    default Base asBase() {
        return match(new Cases<Base>() {
            @Override
            public Base foo(Foo foo) {
                return foo;
            }

            @Override
            public Base bar(Bar bar) {
                return bar;
            }
        });
    }

    static BaseW fromBase(Base base) {
        return new Visitor() {
            BaseW baseW;
            {
                base.accept(this);
            }
            @Override
            public void visit(Foo foo) {
                baseW = new BaseW() {
                    @Override
                    public <X> X match(Cases<X> cases) {
                        return cases.foo(foo);
                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public void visit(Bar bar) {
                baseW = new BaseW() {
                    @Override
                    public <X> X match(Cases<X> cases) {
                        return cases.bar(bar);
                    }
                };
            }
        }.baseW;
    }

    static int useCorrectedVisitor(Base base) {
        return fromBase(base).match(new Cases<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer foo(Foo foo) {
                return (int) foo.getShortValue();
            }

            @Override
            public Integer bar(Bar bar) {
                return bar.getIntValue();
            }
        });
        // or, if church encoding was used:
        // return fromBase(base).match(
        //          foo -> (int) foo.getShortValue(),
        //          bar -> bar.getIntValue()
        // );
    }
}
```

Now (shameless plug), if you don't mind using [derive4j](https://github.com/derive4j/derive4j) (a jsr 269 code generator) the above can be simplified a fair bit, as well as improving syntax:

```java
@org.derive4j.Data // <- generate an BaseWs classe that allows handling
                   // of the interface as an algebraic data type.
interface BaseW {

    interface Cases<X> {
        X foo(Foo foo);
        X bar(Bar bar);
    }

    <X> X match(Cases<X> cases);

    default Base asBase() {
        return match(BaseWs.cases(f -> f, b -> b));
    }

    static BaseW fromBase(Base base) {
        return new Visitor() {
            BaseW baseW;
            {
                base.accept(this);
            }
            @Override
            public void visit(Foo foo) {
                baseW = BaseWs.foo(foo);
            }

            @Override
            public void visit(Bar bar) {
                baseW = BaseWs.bar(bar);
            }
        }.baseW;
    }

    static int useStructuralPatternMatching(Base base) {
        return BaseWs.caseOf(fromBase(base))
            .foo(foo -> (int) foo.getShortValue())
            .bar(Bar::getIntValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can take advantage of Java's generics:

```
interface Visitor<T> {
    T visit(Foo foo);

    T visit(Bar bar);
}

interface Base {
    <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor);
}

interface Foo extends Base {
}

interface Bar extends Base {
}


public final class VisitorExample {
    static class ConcreteFoo implements Foo {
        @Override
        public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
            return visitor.visit(this);
        }
    }

    static class ConcreteBar implements Bar {
        @Override
        public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
            return visitor.visit(this);
        }
    }

    static class ClassNameExtractor implements Visitor<String> {
        @Override
        public String visit(Foo foo) {
            return foo.getClass().getName();
        }

        @Override
        public String visit(Bar bar) {
            return bar.getClass().getName();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Visitor<String> visitor = new ClassNameExtractor();
        Foo foo = new ConcreteFoo();
        Bar bar = new ConcreteBar();

        final String stringResultFromFoo = foo.accept(visitor);
        System.out.println(stringResultFromFoo);

        final String stringResultFromBar = bar.accept(visitor);
        System.out.println(stringResultFromBar);
    }
}
```

By declaring the `accept()` method to return `<T> T`, you can control the return type by using a generic vistor `Visitor<T>`. So you can return anything but primitive types.

The downside of this approach is that if you do not want to return anything, your concrete visitor will have to be of type `Visitor<Void>` and it has to have an annoying `return null` on the `visit()` methods.

Comment: This is true, but the original condition was to not change the visitor interface.

If you can, however, the above approach is fine, and methods that do not need to return anything can be defined `implements Visitor<Void>`, and the methods can return null.

Comment: somehow I've missed the "can't change" part xD

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a member variable in the Visitor:

```
class VisitorSupplier {

    Integer result;

    @Override
    public void visit(Foo foo) {
        result.set(foo.getShortValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Bar bar) {
        result.set(bar.getIntValue());
    }

    public Integer get() {
        return result;
    }

}
```

and use as:

```
VisitorSupplier visitorSupplier = new VisitorSupplier();
bar.accept(visitorSupplier);
return visitorSupplier.get();
```

If you can modify the classes that you visit, or maybe extend, you could add a template method like:

```
public <T, U extends Visitor & java.util.function.Supplier<T>> T acceptSupplier(
    final @NotNull U visitorSupplier
)
{
    accept(visitorSupplier);
    return visitorSupplier.get();
}
```

make your visitor to implement Supplier (with the get method that I already provided):

```
class VisitorSupplier implements java.util.function.Supplier<Integer> { ...
```

and use more elegantly as:

```
return bar.acceptSupplier(new VisitorSupplier());
```

If instead of generic names, based on patterns, you use something more business specific, you can get quite readable code like:

```
Statistics getStatistics() {
    return data.transform(new StatisticsSupplier());
}
```