# Visitor Pattern with Different Return Types for each Node Visited

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I am attempting to implement the Visitor design pattern.
I have a basic understanding of the Visitor pattern and its classic implementation.
I am attempting to morph the visitor pattern to meet my specific goal.

Specific Goal: Add a Return Type to the Visitor Pattern that is specific to which Visitable(node) is being visited.

The classic examples I've seen so far of a visitor returning a specific return type can be achived by generics. But this does not meet my goal:  Add a Return Type to the Visitor Pattern that is specific to which Visitable(node) is being visited.

Here's the other SO questions I looked at before posting mine:
[Visitor Design Pattern - return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593091/visitor-design-pattern-return-type)
[java - Return a value from Visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823571/java-return-a-value-from-visitor)

[Implementing Visitor Pattern while allowing different return types of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164714/implementing-visitor-pattern-while-allowing-different-return-types-of-functions)
--> This question did offer a solution (ie store state inside the visitor, but I didn't love that the caller or consumer of the API would need to remember to get the state back out after calling visit.

Here's some code to show what I mean:

```
public interface IVisitor<TReturn>
{
    TReturn Visit(VisitableClassReturnString visitableClass);

    TReturn Visit(VisitibleClassReturnInt visitibleClass);
}

public class Visitor : IVisitor<string>
{

    public string Visit(VisitableClassReturnString visitableClass)
    {
        // Return type is correct.
        // Logic for visiting (just examples for a return typebelow)
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public string Visit(VisitibleClassReturnInt visitibleClass)
    {
        // Return type is NOT correct.
        // Logic for visiting (just examples for a return typebelow)
        return 0;
    }
}
```

As shown in the code above, I have two different Visitable Classes (nodes) that my visitor wants to visit, in my specific application when I visit those two nodes, I need to return a DIFFERENT type upon visit. Also important to note, that return types being different is only specific to this concrete implementation of Visitor, in all other cases of IVisitor being implmeted the nodes will all likley have the same return type.

That can't be achieved using the single generic, does anyone have any thoughts on how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: ...why are you doing this? What _original_ problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to extract data using the visitor pattern. That's why. I feel like my question well explains my use case. I need to build up a resulting class from the nodes that are visited. As I visit each node, the return types might be different.

Comment: ...you misunderstand the visitor pattern, sorry.

Comment: This is a place to ask questions to better understand.

Comment: I'm using the visitor pattern extract the algorithms that operate on the nodes from the nodes themselves. That is exactly what I am trying to achieve, so I disagree with your comments.

Answer (score 2):

That variation of the Visitor design pattern [is equivalent](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/06/25/visitor-as-a-sum-type) to a [Church-encoding](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/05/22/church-encoding) of a [sum type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). Thus, visiting an element with a Visitor is equivalent to pattern-matching in a statically typed language like F# or Haskell.

Languages that natively support pattern matching are expression-based, so essentially, you can think of the Visitor as an expression. Like pattern matching, the expression must return a value of a unified type, regardless of which kind of element it visits.

Thus, the `TReturn` type in the OP *must* be the same type returned from all nodes.

What you may choose to do, however, is to return another sum type - e.g. something that can be [either](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/06/11/church-encoded-either) a `string` or something else.

In C#, an obvious fall-back value might be null, which should work if you declare `TReturn` as `string?` (nullable `string`).

Another option, particularly if you are traversing a tree-like structure, is to return a collection. The nodes that you don't want to handle can then return an empty collection.

Comment: Thank you, that does make sense and is something I've come across when traversing tree structures before with different algorithms, at some point it boils down to all nodes in the tree being the same type. Which makes sense, but is limiting. So just was curious if anyone was seeing anything clever that could be done. It's not possible is a valid answer as well, I'll hold off accepting an answer to see if there are any other ideas that get generated

Comment: @sdub0800 If tree traversal is indeed your use case, it's a _very_ well-described kind of problem in the FP literature, and you can typically address it with the [tree catamorphism](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/08/05/rose-tree-catamorphism).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll read your article. I haven't heard of most of the terms mentioned there yet, but seems like a good learning opportunity

Answer (score 1):

In the visitor pattern, all Elements are the same type. you can't change the return type based on the element type. When you visit a collection of elements, you expect that the result of each visit will return the same data type. You can't change the result type in the middle of the elements chain.

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

Comment: It unfortunately does not(sorry hit add before I was done). The issue isn't the type of class that is being visited. The issue is the type that must be returned. Your response abstracts the input argument to a generic which is not needed. (method overloading takes care of what you're suggesting.) I do appreciate your help. Let me know how I can clarify my intent.

Comment: I don't know the answers to these questions: why do you need to change the return type dynamically? Do you need multiple visitors with different returned objects on the same visitable object?

Comment: That might be a possible solution to the issue. I need to change the return type because the type being returned will be different and will need to be handled differently by the calling code.

Comment: In the visitor pattern, all Elements are the same type. you can't change the return type based on the element type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256293/discussion-between-r-abbasi-and-sdub0800).

Comment: @sdub0800 I revised the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create an unified return type which will return a type that is necessary.

Let me show an example.

This is a unified return type:

```
public enum MyType
{
    MyString, MyInt, MyClass
}

public class MyTypeValue
{
    public MyTypeValue(MyType myType, object value)
    {
        PropertyType = myType;
        Value = value;
    }

    public MyType PropertyType { get; } // or you can use Type class 
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-8.0

    public object Value { get; }
}
```

And then you can put any data you want and how many you want:

```
public class MyContainer
{
    public List<MyTypeValue> MyVariousTypes { get; } = new();

    public void Add(MyType myType, object value) =>
        MyVariousTypes.Add(new MyTypeValue(myType, value));
}
```

So your Visitor class would look like this:

```
public interface IVisitor
{
    MyContainer Visit(VisitableClassReturnString visitableClass);

    MyContainer Visit(VisitibleClassReturnInt visitibleClass);
}
```

And implemtation of `IVisitor`  would look like this:

```
public class Visitor : IVisitor
{
    MyContainer Visit(VisitableClassReturnString visitableClass)
    {
        MyContainer myContainer= new MyContainer();
        myContainer.Add(MyType.MyString, null);
        return myContainer;
    }

    MyContainer Visit(VisitibleClassReturnInt visitibleClass)
    {
        MyContainer myContainer = new MyContainer();
        myContainer.Add(MyType.Int, null);
        return myContainer;
    }
}
```